# All browsers are requiring a login

Tags: authentication, browser-compatibility

This is the current situation:

- We've setup a SharePoint website with 2 types of users: Visitors and Admins.
- The role of a visitor is that they're only able to see the webpages (no document/library involvement), the role of an administrator is like 'full access'.

A few days ago, the SharePoint site was working like it was supposed to. Visitors were able to see the webpages without any authentication of an login prompt. I've checked the permissions of the default.master page and these are setup correct.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: So your new situation is, that suddenly all visitors needs authentification as visitors as well as admins needs to do this all day long?

Comment: Yes, sorry if it wasn't defined enough.

Comment: Can you confirm if this issue occurs for Site Collection Administrators as well and not just for people with 'Full Control'

Comment: Don't you change anything to your browser policy? I mean the sharepoint site is still in trusted ones? Do you tried to change the security behaviour in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem:

- A calendar that was placed on the defaultpage wasn't accesable by 'anonymous acces'.
- Changed this to 'show elements' and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change anything recently ?

- Any Master page updated but not published / approved ?
- Any Page layout updated but not published / approved ?

Is it occuring on all pages or only on some page ? Did you add a web / user control recently that could require more permissions than what is available for the anonymous user ?

Do you still have your binding under the IIS site ? It will be the first one to challenge you (another site might have *:80 which could take the lead depending on order).

You should fire up Fiddler to see which request and which asset is triggering the authentication. It might be a single (unpublished) image referenced in the master page or a webpart that is forcing a request.

Comment: Yes I did some updates, but I haven't touched the user policy. The website isn't located in the Trusted Websites List but that wasn't a problem at all before this problem (IE was asking for login, other browsers just showed the website as normal visitor.)

Comment: Have you touched the Alternate Access Mappings, do you have a URL for the Internet zone? What zone are your users hitting?

Comment: Never touched the Alternate Access Mappings before. The users are only hitting the normal webpages in the Shared Documents section. There is no interaction on documents or something with the normal user.

Comment: Edited my reply to suggest using Fiddler to check which resource is triggering the authentication handshake

Comment: Is there a way tho check this with Firefox's WebConsole? (A webdeveloppper application inside Firefox). I can catch the authentication event: http://i46.tinypic.com/2lb0wfq.png but I haven't got a clue which item on my default is causing this.

Comment: Are you sure default.aspx is checked-in and approved if approval is on ? Do you have anything specific on that page (eg: a webpart for a specific audience / group) that could trigger additional processing requiring more rights ?

Comment: When I want to check-in the default.aspx it gives me this error: "Deze bewerking kan niet worden uitgevoerd. Het bestand is niet meer uitgecheckt of is verwijderd." EN: This modification cannot be executed. The file hasn't been checked out or is deleted. The SharePoint Designer gives me a green arrow in front of the default.aspx filename (which states that it's currently 'checked-out'.

Comment: So someone took this file (exclusively) out for editing and didn't checked it in. You need to check it in to allow all users to access it.
You can also create another page and check-it-in (and afterward set it as the landing page) to ensure that this was indeed the issue.

Comment: I am the one and only user of the SharePoint environment at the moment. Is there a way to check in by just using the online environment? (I don't have access to the server-environment, just total-control permissions with my account on the site)

Comment: @pigeon I never changed the Alternate Access Mappings settings. Maybe I should do now?